# sharing an editable edge animate file

Tags: adobe, file-sharing, adobe-edge

I am trying to email an Edge Animate project to someone but the only way I can figure it out is to publish it and then send him the .oam in with an Adobe Muse file and even then there is no way for him to edit the Edge Animate file. What must I do to be able to send an editable Edge Animate project? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the *.an file, or create a template which will give you a *.antmpl file

To open a *.antmpl, create from template, import, select